# Using nbconvert to make a pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, ipython

I am having a problem converting some text rendered with IPython.core.display.Latex into the correct tex code to make a pdf.

[github page](https://github.com/damontallen/nbconvert-latex-failure)

[Static Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/github.com/damontallen/nbconvert-latex-failure/raw/master/Latex_test.ipynb)

Does the text in the variable "out" need to be written differently or is this a problem with nbconvert?

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're having more clearly? Do you get an error from tex? Does the output look wrong?

Comment: I get a tex error.  The log file is on the github page.  Nbconvert does not create a pdf file due to the tex error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that ordinary text should not be placed inside '$' tags,
the problem in your case are the empty lines `$ $`. Here, the space gets dropped during the conversion and thus, results in an additional pair of `$$`s, which confuses LaTeX.

A simple solution is to write `${}$` instead, and make sure the strings end with `$` and not with an empty space.